# Vue-JS Displaying other data than the v-model in an input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, v-model

Here's part of my code:

```
data() {
    return {
        dossier: [{
               caisse: '', // I change this value with v-model
               nom_caisse: 'exempleName' // I want to display this dynamic value in the input
        }],
    }
}

<input v-model="d.caisse"/>
```

I just put in the essential information. I didn't put the for. I'm going to go through my "dossier" array and interact on "caisse". It works but I would like to display another field in the input of the "nom_caisse" table. Do you know how to display another value than the v-model?

Edit "Solution":

I've come up with a solution that's a little hard to explain. I put my "d.caisse_name" field in v-model but I get the value of the input with jQuery to search in my api. So my v-model to be different from the value of the input... I understand myself :) Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Did you try using **v-text** ? I'm not sure but it could work.

Comment: I just tried v-text='d.nom_caisse' and :v-text='d.nom_caisse'    Both do nothing..

Comment: Maybe try :value.

Comment: With :value i have an error : :value="d.nom_caisse" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

Comment: so what is d here ?

Comment: I make v-for d in dossiers. But I have found a solution that I filled out in my base post